# Как делать POST запрос c Axios(Vue)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Как правильно делать POST запрос с Axios.

```
methods: {
      clear () {
        this.$refs.login.reset()
      },
      logIn: function () {
        Axios.post('http://192.168.1.116:8000', {
          login: this.name,
          password: this.password
        })
          .then(()=>{
            console.log('qqwe')
            this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.redirect || '/tamam')
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('q')
          })
      },
    }
```

Есть такой скрипт. Правильно ли? Сервер показывает пустые значения.

Comment: А на сервере что? Может там Basic Auth, тогда неправильно. Ну и код вырван из контекста.

Answer (score 0):

```
methods: {
  clear () {
    this.$refs.login.reset()
  },
  logIn: function () {
    Axios.post('http://192.168.1.116:8000', {
      login: this.name,
      password: this.password
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log('Ответ сервера:', res)
      this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.redirect || '/tamam')
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log('err', err)
    })
  },
}
```